# How are the tags which are shown in the question title chosen

Tags: support, tags, title

When a question is asked, I notice a tag is appended to the question title as the tab title in my browser. For example when a question is tagged [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms). The tab title will be *c# - Question title*.

On pets private beta, If a question is tagged dogs, health, The tab title will be *health-Question title*.

How is the tag that is appended to the question title determined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tags on a question are ordered based on the number of questions with that tag.  The first tag is the one that is added to the page title.